# How to lookup for documents within a polygon from another collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

I have a MongoDB `collection A` with several hundreds of documents like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6439bfc481c8ad39798d1009"),
    "citi_id" : "place_qedaw2132",
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -79.8922549,
            34.0013755
        ]
    },
    "record_timestamp" : "2013-03-06T12:41:48-05:00"
}
```

I have another MongoDB `collection B` with 1 document like this where `polygon_coord` contains an array of size 302 elements:

```js
{
    "_id" : null,
    "polygon_coord" : [
        [
            -79.8895483,
            34.0467802
        ],
        [
            -79.9060312,
            34.0183378
        ],
        .......300 more elements
    ]
}
```

My objective is to find all documents (cities) of `collection A` which are within the polygon coordinates of `polygon_coord` in `collection B`.

I have tried the following:
I copied the array of 302 elements manually, and created a query like this:

```js
db.getCollection("collection_A").find(
  {
     geometry: {
       $geoWithin: { $polygon: [ 
           
        [
            -79.8895483,
            34.0467802
        ],
        [
            -79.9060312,
            34.0183378
        ],
        .......300 more elements
        
           
      ] }
     }
  }
)
```

And it worked! It gave me the correct results. But, this was manual. I researched a lot and found that I have to use $lookup operator, but I am unable to form any query no matter whatever I try. Please help with this.